# Getting an error from streamlit file_uploader

Tags: python, tensorflow, streamlit

I am getting this error when trying to predict the image from loading it from streamlit file_uploader. the process is working fine when I try directly loading the image in ide. but the problem is arising with **streamlit** **file_uploader**. i can't figure in which file type the streamlit is uploading the file. Please help me with how I can upload a custom image and predict it with the Keras model.

It is showing this error.

> ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=474x266 at 0x1C7B84190A0>) with an unsupported type (<class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>) to a Tensor.

My code is

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import streamlit as st
from PIL import  Image

class_names = ['apple_pie',....'] # total 101 food name.

# loading the model
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('effi_080_second.h5') 

file = st.file_uploader('Upload a file', type='jpg') # asking for file

image = Image.open(file)
st.image(image) # showing the image.


img = tf.io.read_file(file)
img = tf.image.decode_image(img)
# rsize the image
img = tf.image.resize(image, size=(224,224))
img = tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
pred = model.predict(img)

pred_cls = class_names[pred.argmax()] # getting the class name index
st.write(pred_cls) # writting the class name
```

The full error is

> ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=474x266 at 0x1C7B84190A0>) with an unsupported type (<class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>) to a Tensor.
>
> Traceback:
> File "e:\anaconda3\envs\webapp_streamlit\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 338, in _run_script
> exec(code, module.**dict**)
>
> File "E:\WebApp_streamlit\image_process.py", line 120, in 
> img = tf.image.resize(image, size=(224,224))
>
> File "e:\anaconda3\envs\webapp_streamlit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 201, in wrapper
> return target(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "e:\anaconda3\envs\webapp_streamlit\lib\site-packages  \tensorflow\python\ops\image_ops_impl.py", line 1540, in resize_images_v2
> return _resize_images_common(
>
> File "e:\anaconda3\envs\webapp_streamlit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\image_ops_impl.py", line 1210, in _resize_images_common
> images = ops.convert_to_tensor(images, name='images')
>
> File "e:\anaconda3\envs\webapp_streamlit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1499, in convert_to_tensor
> ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
>
> File "e:\anaconda3\envs\webapp_streamlit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 338, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
> return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
>
> File "e:\anaconda3\envs\webapp_streamlit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 263, in constant
> return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
> File "e:\anaconda3\envs\webapp_streamlit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 275, in _constant_impl
> return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
> File "e:\anaconda3\envs\webapp_streamlit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 300, in _constant_eager_impl
> t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
> File "e:\anaconda3\envs\webapp_streamlit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 98, in convert_to_eager_tensor
> return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)`

Please help me with this, I want to know how to predict an image from streamlit file uploader and then predict it from the keras model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have the image in the buffer you can try this.

```
import streamlit as st
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

file = st.file_uploader("Upload an image", type=["png", "jpg", "jpeg"])

if file is not None:
    image = Image.open(file)

    st.image(
        image,
        caption=f"You amazing image has shape",
        use_column_width=True,
    )

    img_array = np.array(image)
    img = tf.image.resize(img_array, size=(224,224))
    img = tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
```